# Admob - gradle configuration error

Tags: java, android

I've followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start, but I'm stucked at gradle configuration. I've added line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
```

to build.gradle (of application) like in tutorial, but error "Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0" appeared. Admob writers says, that android studio will offer download if that is missing, but I've only got error in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You need to download "Google Repository" from Android SDK.